# exe to service

Tags: windows-services, exe

I have exe file. i want run it as windows service.

I am new to windows services.can anybody help me?

Thanks
Suneetha.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [SrvAny](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197) that comes with the Windows Resource Kit which you can use to do this on the command line.  You can use that if you don't have access to the source code of your program.

Answer (score 1):

SC.exe from Microsoft
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Or:
http://kennethhunt.com/archives/001728.html

Answer (score 1):

As both Dave and Reuben recommend, SRVANY will do the basic job of running your EXE file as a service, but you should be cautious when going that route. Please review [this article comparing SRVANY to our commercial application AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html), which is designed to run any application as a Windows Service.

Good Luck!